# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT when starting Ionic Project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, proxy, firewall

[The Error Code I get right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdW3K.png)

Hello Guys.

For hours I've been trying to set up a new Ionic Framework Project.

Node.js, Cordova, Ionic... are all up to date.

It seems like I'm behind a Proxy Server or something so I tried to set up HTTP_PROXY and IONIC_HTTP_PROXY System variables with a Proxy Server I found in an open list. I used "109.107.200.151:8080" but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Has anyone an idea? If you need further information just ask.

After using:

```
ionic start myapp --verbose
```

I received:[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJDIm.png)

Comment: Can you please try executing `ionic start myapp --verbose` command and post us what you're receiving?

Comment: @DavidR i edited my post

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text error messages. Copy paste the text into your question so that it's both searchable and still accessible if your links to the pictures break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling your current version of `ionic` by using the below command,

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Once done, try installing the latest version of `ionic` using this command,

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
```

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: The new Installation is running, but why couldn't i use     "$ npm install -g ionic@latest" ? only "npm install -g ionic@latest" worked...

Comment: No the Installation is still running...? Takes way too Long... It says "[    ..............] | fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/wrap-ansi" right now

Comment: Somehow i could delete all wrong Proxys. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

As per the ionic doc https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cli-getting-timout-when-start-a-new-project/13974, the below solution works to solve this issue

Open command prompt and run the below command to set the proxy

set PROXY=http://mycompany_proxy.com:proxy_port_number

for e.g set PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany.com:3148

Comment: Thank you, my company use proxy and i was create new ionic project success